DMARC Authentication in SendGrid is expecting a different value from the current one
I have one SendGrid account softtimur@mycompany.com, I have been using it to send transactional emails from softtimur@mycompany.com. When I check the account softtimur@mycompany.com, I realized that the authentication of DMARC of mycompany.com failed (even though we can send emails from there); the expected value for _dmarc.mycompany.com is v=DMARC1; p=none;.
Then, I went to CloudFlare to check the current DNS of mycompany.com, I see that the value is v=DMARC1; p=reject; sp=none; rua=mailto:dmarc@mailinblue.com!10m; ruf=mailto:dmarc@mailinblue.com!10m; rf=afrf; pct=100; ri=86400. I believe this value was set by my previous consultant to send emails from ESPs such as AWS SES.
Does anyone know what value it should be? How could I make the authentication in SendGrid succeeded?

Question looks suspiciously similar to this one. In short, stay away from operators that depend on your policy set to v=DMARC1; p=none; — that policy is bad for you and for the Internet, it's as if there was "no policy". Your current policy is reasonable, I'd say you better keep it and insist that your mail must signed and authorized according to this policy. Ask them for their IP addresses or names you can put into your SPF; ask them for their public key and selector for the DKIM.

But the status of the authentication of DMARC of mycompany.com in SendGrid is "Failed". Should not I do something with regards to that?

Ask them for their IP addresses or names you can put into your SPF; ask them for their public key and selector for the DKIM. If they refuse, don't use their crappy services.

DMARC itself doesn't authenticate specific senders. Instead, the DMARC record instructs receiving mail servers on how to handle messages that fail both SPF and DKIM authentication. In your case, the p=reject policy tells receivers to block unauthenticated emails from @mycompany.com addresses. There's nothing wrong with this policy.
If emails sent via SendGrid are failing authentication, you should review your DKIM and SPF setup. SendGrid requires you to add CNAME records to your domain's DNS settings that point to their DKIM TXT records. Additionally, you should add include:sendgrid.net to your SPF record to authorize SendGrid to send emails on behalf of your domain.
Once you have made the changes, visit https://dmarcchecker.app/ and send a test mail to the provided address to ensure everything is working as intended.
